# 'ManagementClass' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Management'

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, mac-address

Hi i'm using this method for get the mac address

```
public string GetMACAddress()
{
    System.Management.ManagementClass mc = default(System.Management.ManagementClass);
    ManagementObject mo = default(ManagementObject);
    mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");

    ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
    foreach (var mo in moc)
    {
        if (mo.Item("IPEnabled") == true)
        {
            return mo.Item("MacAddress").ToString();
        }else
            return null;

    }

}
```

but i receive this error

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ManagementClass' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Management' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

What i have to do for fix it?

thanks

Comment: Read the step by step way to add the reference of [System.Management](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22223788/3240038) into your project.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to [add a reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708954.aspx) to System.Management in your project.

Comment: link is broken :(

Comment: Updated link! :)

Comment: Is it working in 2017? I couldn't find a System.management in the reference pop up. I checked all libs start with System. but still got the same error. Do I need to install anything on Mac?

Comment: Not sure about Mac specifically unfortunately, but if I search System.Management in VS 2017 I get [results](https://imgur.com/a/veA9N)

Answer (score 13):

I think the issue here is that you don't have a proper "pointer" to the System.Management assembly. You must:

- **Use a using statement** - in some of your code, you didn't prefix classes w/ System.Management, so you should either include:

a.)

```
using System.Management
```

or

b.) a using block

```
using(System.Management) 
{  
//your code goes here
}
```

Next, you need to have a **real assembly reference**. To do this in Visual Studio, right click on your project (or on References) in the Solution Explorer window and click Add Reference. After the list tabulates, find System.Management.dll in the .NET tab. Once you add it, it should work!

Answer (score 8):

In the solution explorer:

1. add reference
2. find and add system.management in .NET class

that's it

Answer (score 3):

Have you got the System.Management assembly referenced?

Answer (score 2):

Please first make sure you add the Library `Systems.Management` in to your project references.

Then just use that referred assembly by including in your class.

```
using System.Windows;
```